# Java - sound sequences are played faster/slower on different computers

Tags: java

I am playing a sequence of very short tones. It seems to me that the tones are coming slightly faster on some computers. Yet I am using a Timer. Any ideas why this could happen?

```
        int thistimer = 200;
        int tone;
        for (tone = 0; tone < thissequence.size(); tone++) {
            final int thistone = thissequence.get(tone);
            final int toneNum = tone;
            new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            playTone(thistone);
                            if (visualise)
                                visualiseButton(thistone);                         
                            if (toneNum == thissequence.size()-1)                           
                                    enable4buttons();

                        }},
                    thistimer
            );
            thistimer = thistimer + 333;
        }
```

Do some systems wait for the tone to be finished before starting the timer?

Comment: because not all computers have the same processing speed. for instance, your average x486 against the latest intel chip ... same file will take the 486 (assuming it'll be able to play it) a lot longer. then, you also need to take into account that some computers have(n't) multiple processors, additional ram, ... basically, all resources that might have an impact on this

Comment: @Stultuske -  Timing (for example using `Timer()`) is implemented at the OS level using hardware timers that are not directly dependent on the system clock frequency, instruction set, or stuff like that.

Comment: Mmm I see. I thought the 333 was specified in ms though?

Comment: Any ways around this then?